# Chat Python - Errno 9 - Bad File Descriptor

Tags: python, thread, chat

Estou desenvolvendo (para estudo apenas) um código para um chat em python, e me deparei com um erro durante a comunicação cliente-servidor, gostaria de uma orientação acerca do mesmo, visto que não consigo identificar uma soluçao. Segue o código e a imagem do erro.

Servidor:

```
import threading # threads
from socket import * # sockets

clientes_conn = [] # Lista de conexões/clientes
clientes_name = [] # Lista dos nomes das conexões

class minhaThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, threadName, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = threadID
        self.name = threadName
        self.conn = conn
    def run(self):
        chat_geral(self.conn,self.name)

'''
param == 1 => Mensagem do sistema
param == 2 => Mensagem do cliente
'''
def enviar_mensagem(msg, name, param):
    if param == 1:
        for conn in clientes_conn:
            conn.send(msg)
        print msg 
    else:
        for conn in clientes_conn:
            conn.send("("+name+"): "+msg)
        print "("+name+"): "+msg 

def adicionar_cliente(conn, _id):
    while 1:
        message2 = conn.recv(1024)
        if message2 == "":
            continue
        if message2 in clientes_name:
            serverSocket.send("O nome informado está sendo usado por um cliente atualmente.\n")
            continue
        clientes_conn.append(conn)
        clientes_name.append(message2)
        success = "Cliente '"+str(message2)+"' conectado com sucesso!"
        enviar_mensagem(success, message2, 1)

        # Entra no terceiro while 1
        thread = minhaThread(_id, message2, conn).start()

        clientes_conn.remove(conn)
        clientes_name.remove(message2)
        conn.close()
        break

def chat_geral(conn, name):
    while 1:
        msg = conn.recv(1024)
        if msg == "Sair" or msg == "sair":
            sair = "Cliente "+name+" está saindo do chat."
            enviar_mensagem(sair, name, 1)
            break
        enviar_mensagem(msg, name, 2)

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 8080
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSocket.bind((serverName,serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print "Servidor TCP esperando conexoes na porta %d ..." % (serverPort)

id_padrao = 0
while 1:
    connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
    print "Cliente "+str(address[1])+" tentando se conectar..."
    adicionar_cliente(connectionSocket, id_padrao)
    id_padrao += 1
serverSocket.close()
```

Cliente:

```
from socket import * # sockets
import threading # threads

class minhaThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadName, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = threadName
        self.conn = conn
    def run(self):
        chat_geral(self.name,self.conn)

def conectar_chat(conn):
    while 1:
        msg = raw_input("Digite seu nome: ")
        conn.send(msg)
        message = conn.recv(1024)
        print message
        if message.find("conectado com sucesso") != -1:
            thread = minhaThread(msg,conn).start()
            break

def chat_geral(name,conn):
    while 1:
        msg = raw_input("Digite (mensagem/comando): ")
        conn.send(msg)
        msg2 = conn.recv(1024)
        if msg2 == "saindo do chat" and msg.find(name) != -1:
            print "Desconectando do server."
            break
        print msg2

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 8080
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))

conectar_chat(clientSocket)

clientSocket.close()
```

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ola Bruno, excelente primeira questão. Você faria a gentileza de editar sua questão e colar o erro de maneira textual (screenshoots são sempre complicados).

Comment: Fiz há pouco tempo um chat simples em python 3.5.2 , coloquei-o agora no git hug: github.com/Miguel-Frazao/simple-chat-python3 , veja o que acha. Pode reduzir muito o código do lado servidor se apagar os prints que ele faz, na realidade não são necessários, é mais para rastrear o que se passa

Comment: Como mencionado em um comentário, o erro de forma textual ficaria melhor de analisar, mas veja se [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15958099/2879341) não se aplica ao seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é bem simples.
Logo que um cliente conecta, você utiliza o seguinte método/função:

```
def adicionar_cliente(conn, _id):
    while 1:
        message2 = conn.recv(1024)
        if message2 == "":
            continue
        if message2 in clientes_name:
            serverSocket.send("O nome informado está sendo usado por um cliente atualmente.\n")
            continue
        clientes_conn.append(conn)
        clientes_name.append(message2)
        success = "Cliente '"+str(message2)+"' conectado com sucesso!"
        enviar_mensagem(success, message2, 1)

        # Entra no terceiro while 1
        thread = minhaThread(_id, message2, conn).start()

        clientes_conn.remove(conn)
        clientes_name.remove(message2)
        conn.close()
        break
```

O problema é que logo após você criar a thread (`thread = minhaThread(_id, message2, conn).start()`), você fecha a conexão (`conn.close()`). Logo a thread tenta trabalhar com um socket já fechado - o que impossibilita a comunicação.

Você vai precisar remodelar o seu código, de maneira que a thread termine a conexão, simples assim :)

Código provavelmente correto (já que não rodei, não vou dar garantias):

```
import threading # threads
from socket import * # sockets

clientes_conn = [] # Lista de conexões/clientes
clientes_name = [] # Lista dos nomes das conexões

class minhaThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, threadName, conn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = threadID
        self.name = threadName
        self.conn = conn
    def run(self):
        chat_geral(self.conn,self.name)

'''
param == 1 => Mensagem do sistema
param == 2 => Mensagem do cliente
'''
def enviar_mensagem(msg, name, param):
    if param == 1:
        for conn in clientes_conn:
            conn.send(msg)
        print msg 
    else:
        for conn in clientes_conn:
            conn.send("("+name+"): "+msg)
        print "("+name+"): "+msg 

def adicionar_cliente(conn, _id):
    while 1:
        message2 = conn.recv(1024)
        if message2 == "":
            continue
        if message2 in clientes_name:
            serverSocket.send("O nome informado está sendo usado por um cliente atualmente.\n")
            continue
        clientes_conn.append(conn)
        clientes_name.append(message2)
        success = "Cliente '"+str(message2)+"' conectado com sucesso!"
        enviar_mensagem(success, message2, 1)

        # Entra no terceiro while 1
        thread = minhaThread(_id, message2, conn).start()
        break

def chat_geral(conn, name):
    while 1:
        msg = conn.recv(1024)
        if msg == "Sair" or msg == "sair":
            sair = "Cliente "+name+" está saindo do chat."
            enviar_mensagem(sair, name, 1)
            break
        enviar_mensagem(msg, name, 2)

    # O cliente desconectou
    clientes_conn.remove(conn)
    clientes_name.remove(message2)
    conn.close()

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 8080
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSocket.bind((serverName,serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print "Servidor TCP esperando conexoes na porta %d ..." % (serverPort)

id_padrao = 0
while 1:
    connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
    print "Cliente "+str(address[1])+" tentando se conectar..."
    adicionar_cliente(connectionSocket, id_padrao)
    id_padrao += 1
serverSocket.close()
```

Um problema que já vejo logo de cara é o acesso nas variáveis "clientes_conn" e "clientes_name", que deve ser modificado, já que podem acontecer erros de acesso simultâneo por múltiplas threads (na hora que clientes se desconectarem ao mesmo tempo).

Abraços